# Need to write an applescript to do a series of wget commands for downloading images from a list

Tags: macos, applescript, wget

I have wget installed on my Mac and it works great. I'm trying to automate the process of pulling thousands of images by using an applescript to do it, however, I'm missing something in the formatting.

How can I make an applescript that will send a wget, wait til the file is downloaded, then issue the next wget command, etc. all in the same terminal window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set downloads to {"http://google.com/", "http://example.com/"}
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    repeat with page in downloads
        do script "wget " & page in tab 1 of window 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm pretty much an apple script newbie here, so forgive my lack of understanding, but where would I reference my list of URLs?